# LASlib internal error - reading las file with lidR

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

Should I assume that the following error occurs because the file is corrupt? Is there any way I can get more information out of this file?

```r
bad_las <- readLAS("~/Downloads/3102_309374.las")
#> ERROR: reading 151140850 bytes of data into header.evlrs[0].data
#> ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name '/Users/lucasj/Downloads/3102_309374.las'
#> Error: LASlib internal error. See message above.
#> ERROR: reading 151140850 bytes of data into header.evlrs[0].data
#> ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name '/Users/lucasj/Downloads/3102_309374.las'
#> Error in C_reader(ifiles, ofile, select, filter, filter_wkt) : 
#>   LASlib internal error. See message above.
packageVersion("lidR")
#> [1] ‘3.0.5’
packageVersion("rlas")
#> [1] ‘1.3.7’
```

**UPDATE**
`lasinfo` and `las2txt` produce the following error:

```bsh
ERROR: reading 151140850 bytes of data into header.evlrs[0].data
ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name '3102_309374.las'
ERROR: could not open lasreader
```

Comment: Can `lasinfo` or `las2txt` from `lastools` read the file?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the same issue I reported [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/rlas/issues/43) (which is still open, so there's no solution in `rlas` yet). Ultimately, I had to use lastools' `las2las` (on an entire acquisition) to loop through and read/rewrite all the files and it fixed it. Based on that issue on github, I've been contacted by a few others and the `las2las` approach worked for them too...

Comment: This means that an update of `laslib` in `rlas` should fix the issue

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. `las2las` produces the same errors as above with `las2txt` and `lasinfo`.

Comment: Update lastools and if this does not help your file is definitively corrupted in a irrecoverable way